# Curvature scalars and singularities

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature, singularities

Without resorting to the singularity theorems, can we say that there is a singularity at a particular $r=\textrm{constant}$ if the value of the Ricci and Kretschmann scalars get infinitely large at that particular value of $r$?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: @Qmechanic: is there a proof that a divergent curvature implies geodesic incompleteness? Or does the word singularity just mean curvature singularity here? Because it doesn't seem impossible to have a complete spacetime where the curvature diverges as $r\to\infty$, which could then be brought to finite $r$ by a coordinate transformation.

Comment: OP should clarify what he is asking.

Comment: If a singularity can be made to go away by a coordinate transformation then its not a real singularity right? Also, is there any other type of singularity other than curvature singularity?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, if *scalar* curvature invariant diverges, this means that there is a “curvature singularity”. However, curvature singularity alone does not necessarily implies that the spacetime around it is incurably bad, for instance curvature singularity might be *mild* enough that is possible to extend geodesics across it, so the spacetime would be geodesically complete.

For example consider a static spherically symmetric spacetime:
$$
 ds^2= A(r)dt^2 - B(r) dr^2 - r^2 (d\theta^2+\sin^2 \theta d\phi^2).
$$
We can choose the functions $A$ and $B$ varying near their flat space value of $1$, and having continuous first derivatives while having the second derivative $A''$ diverging in a mild manner (say, like $|r-r_0|^{-\epsilon}$ with some small $\epsilon$) near the sphere $r=r_0$. For example, we could chose a flat space metric for $r<r_0 - \delta$, Schwarzshild metric with some $m\ll r_0 $ for $r > r_0+\delta$, and non-Ricci flat interpolating metric with diverging second derivatives in the thin region $|r-r_0| < \delta $. The physical interpretation of  such spacetime would be the thin material spherical shell with diverging stress-energy tensor on the sphere $r=r_0$ and hence diverging Ricci and Kretschmann scalar,  but finite surface density and finite total mass. And since Christoffel symbols are regular at the sphere $r=r_0$, there would be no problem with continuing geodesics through it. Such spacetime is geodesically complete and has the same causal structure as the Minkowski space.

Note, that while geodesic incompleteness is a quite often used test of singularities of spacetime, it is not universal. For example, in string theory instead of geodesic incompleteness, which is based on a motion of test point particle it is more natural to consider the motion of test string, and so, some geodesically incomplete spacetimes could be “regular” from stringy viewpoint.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I may ask a follow up, if a spacetime has a place where the curvature scalars "blow up" and there is an apparent horizon, does that immediately imply the presence of a black hole?

Comment: @jboy: under the *weak cosmic censorship conjecture* it does, but this conjecture has not been proven (despite being formulated more than fifty years ago), and there are some known counterexamples (usually involving somewhat unphysical assumptions), so precise conditions under which this is true are unknown.